# is this language regular and why pumping lemma doesn't work?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I was told that this language is regular but as I can show below, pumping lemma is not working for it. What am I doing wrong? Is this language really regular? Why?
[image]

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally submitted your improved version [as a new question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97886/how-to-come-up-with-regular-expression-or-fsa-for-such-language). What you should do instead is click the "edit" link at the bottom of your question (but above these comments).

Comment: [Please do not post a screenshot or photo of text](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of the pumping lemma is incorrect. First, to show that the pumping lemma fails to hold in the case of your string $S$ (and thereby prove $L$ non-regular), you would have to show that *every* choice of $y$ fails. You've picked a specific $y$.

Second, $S'$ is in $L$. Simply take the whole $S'$ string as $b$ and let $a$ be empty. *Every* string of zeros and ones is in $L$ the same way, so $L = \{0, 1\}^*$ and $L$ is regular.

Answer (score 8):

It's a "trick" question. The language is regular because
\begin{align*}
\{aba^{\mathrm{R}}\mid a,b\in\{0,1\}^*\}
    &= \big\{\varepsilon b\varepsilon^{\mathrm{R}}\mid b\in\{0,1\}^*\big\}
       \cup \big\{a b a^{\mathrm{R}}\mid a\in\{0,1\}^+,\ b\in\{0,1\}^*\big\}\\
    &= \{0,1\}^*
       \cup \big\{a b a^{\mathrm{R}}\mid a\in\{0,1\}^+,\ b\in\{0,1\}^*\big\}\\
    &= \{0,1\}^*\,.
\end{align*}

Comment: But then there must be something wrong in the solution given in the question?

Comment: @rus9384 Yes, as shown in [Daniel Mroz's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97884/9550).

Answer (score 6):

Write the word $s'$ as

$$
s' = 0^{(p-\beta)} \left(1^p01^p0^{\beta} \right)0^{(p -\beta)}
$$
to see that it is in fact in $L$.